# Loading values into an array from two different arrays iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, for-loop, nsmutablearray

Here I am having a situation, I'm using the following code:

```
int x=0;
for (int i=0; i<=[arrayDeals count]-1; i++) {
    x++;
    //NSString *deal = [arrayDeals objectAtIndex:i];
    combinedArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:
                    [CustomObject customObjectWithName:[arrayDeals objectAtIndex:i] andNumber:x],nil];
}
```

I need to load the values from arrayDeals and the 'x' value into combinedArr. So, I put this in a for loop. But i got only one value from each arrays. What is went wrong here? Please help me. (here CustomObject is a NSObject) 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there are many things wrong with the code you posted, but I think this is what you want:

```
int x = 0;

NSMutableArray *combinedArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]:
NSInteger count = [arrayDeals count];
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    x++;
     CustomObject *customObject =  [CustomObject customObjectWithName:[arrayDeals objectAtIndex:i] andNumber:x];

   [combinedArr addObject:customObject];
}
```

---

To give you some idea of what is wrong with the code you posted:

```
combinedArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:
                    [CustomObject customObjectWithName:[arrayDeals objectAtIndex:i] andNumber:x],nil];
```

Here you create a new `NSMutableArray` to which you assign an new object to taked the object from the array `arrayDeals`. But you create this `NSMutableArray` for every item in the array `arrayDeals` and you assign them to the same variable.

So each iteration you leak the `NSMutableArray`.

Also :

```
for (int i=0; i<=[arrayDeals count]-1; i++) {
```

is the same as

```
 for (int i=0; i < [arrayDeals count]; i++) {
```

but the count is called every time you iterate, so as per my example I saved the count in a int to just speed things up.

---

You could even speed the code up using fast Enumeration:

```
NSInteger x = 0;    
NSMutableArray *combinedArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]:

for (id object in arrayDeals) {
    id secondObject = [secondArray itemAtIndex:x];
    // Arrays start at 0 so only up it after we've got the object.
    x++;
     CustomObject *customObject =  [CustomObject customObjectWithName:object andNumber:x];

   [combinedArr addObject:customObject];
}
```

Comment: awesome man....!!! thanks. One more, in the last method, for (id object in arrayDeals)....if i need to add value from another array in the place of 'x', how can I do that?

Comment: At the same poistion as in `arraDeals`?

Comment: Actually i wanted to perform a sort action, arrayDeals contains some string values,and the another array say dateArray contains NSDate values. I have got the code to sort the dateArray contains some int values. But what if it is contains, NSDate values?

Comment: Have a look at [`NSSortDescriptor`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Because this has nothing to do with you original question.